# Curses Functions in C,print out default message and blinking

Tags: c, printing, sleep, curses

Display a blinking message in the center of the screen. If the user supplies a message on the command line, your program should display that message, otherwise the default message is displayed. Use the sleep function to pause the program between printing the message and then erasing it.
Here is what i did so far,i only can print and blinking the message is what i input, but i can not print the default message.

```
#include <ncurses.h>            
#include <string.h> 
 
int main()
{
    char mesg[50]="";       
    int row,col;                         
    initscr();  
    scanf("%s",&mesg);
    getmaxyx(stdscr,row,col);
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        if(i%2==1)
            standout();    
        mvprintw(row/2,col/2,"%s",mesg);
        sleep(1);
        if(i%2!=1)
            standend();
        mvprintw(row/2,col/2,"%s",mesg);                                
        refresh();
    }
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

thanks for you guys help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `main` as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` (or `char **argv`) to access command line parameters. Assuming `argc >= 1`, the program name will be in `argv[0]`, and if `argc > 1`, the command line parameter strings will be in `argv[1]` through to `argv[argc - 1]`. `argv[argc]` will be a null pointer.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *mesg;
    int row,col;
    int startcol;

    if (argc > 1) {
        mesg = argv[1];
    } else {
        mesg = "Default message";
    }
    initscr();
    getmaxyx(stdscr,row,col);
    if (strlen(mesg) > col) {
        startcol = 0;
    } else {
        startcol = (col - strlen(mesg)) / 2;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        if(i%2==1)
            standout();    
        mvprintw(row/2,startcol,"%s",mesg);
        sleep(1);
        if(i%2!=1)
            standend();
        mvprintw(row/2,startcol,"%s",mesg);                                
        refresh();
    }
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

Comment: thanks for you help lan Abbott it is works, i am appreciate

Comment: would you tell me what is startcol and why i need using if (strlen(mesg) > col) do this step? thans for you help

Comment: @Eren `startcol` is the column where the message should start so that the message is centered on the line, taking its length into account. The `if (strlen(mesg) > col)` part is just to stop `startcol` going negative.